# Mail server that supports duplicate file detection?

Tags: email, gmail, duplicate, hashing, mail-server

AFAIK, Google mail servers (gmail) can detect duplicate files. For example, if you receive a big file as attachment that exactly exists in someone else's inbox, google avoids storing the file twice, but instead it will make pointers to the same file.

This is a great feature. For instance, if a file is **K** MB and is stored by **U** users in their inboxes, it will be stored once, and (  **(K-1) * U** ) MB will be freed.

I am wondering if there is any open web-server application that supports this feature.

Comment: I guess your equation should be **K * (U-1)**

Answer (score 2):

Dovecot supports attachment deduplication (under the name "single instance storage") when using the `mdbox` storage format, [since version 2.1](http://kevat.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2013-March/089072.html). You'll need [these settings](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.mail.imap.dovecot/75748) in `10-mail.conf`:

```
mail_attachment_dir = ...
mail_attachment_min_size = 128k
mail_attachment_fs = sis posix
mail_attachment_hash = %{sha1}
```